# Selecting elements from a list where the order is set by another list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, core-language

I have two lists, list `A` and list `B`. All of the elements of `A` are members of `B`. The order of `B` is fixed but the order of `A` is random. I need to arrange the elements in `A` as given in `B`.

Example let `A`

```
A={5,2,8}
```

and `B` is

```
B={9,2,6,8,5,1}
```

I need to reorder `A` to be:

```
A={2,8,5}
```

I'm looking for a clever one-liner. This is similar to [How to order a list to match the order of another list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100084/how-to-order-a-list-to-match-the-order-of-another-list) but there the two lists have the same length. I tried some variations on adding some padding.

From the clever solutions below I have settled on using:

```
OrderLike[A_List,B_List]:=Cases[Alternatives @@ A]@B;
```

Which has been shown to be the fasted and most poetic. 
(However, Its poeticness is a subjective matter unlike its speed.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SortBy[Position[B, #]&]@A
```

> {2, 8, 5}

and

```
SortBy[PositionIndex @ B] @ A (* thanks: WReach *)
```

> {2, 8, 5}

Also,

```
Cases[Alternatives @@ A] @ B
Select[MatchQ[Alternatives @@ A]] @ B
DeleteCases[Except[Alternatives @@ A]] @ B
```

**Update:** Some timing comparisons:

```
f1[a_, b_] := SortBy[FirstPosition[b, #] &]@a;
f2[a_, b_] := SortBy[Position[b, #] &]@a;
f3[a_, b_] := SortBy[PositionIndex @ b]@a;
f4[a_, b_] := Cases[Alternatives @@ a] @ b;
f5[a_, b_] := Select[MatchQ[Alternatives @@ a]] @ b;
f6[a_, b_] := DeleteCases[Except[Alternatives @@ a]] @b;
funcs = {"f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6"};

SeedRandom[1]
nb = 10000;
na = 5;
b = RandomSample[Range[10^6], nb];
a = RandomSample[b, na];
t1 = First@RepeatedTiming[r1 = f1[a, b];];
t2 = First@RepeatedTiming[r2 = f2[a, b];];
t3 = First@RepeatedTiming[r3 = f3[a, b];];
t4 = First@RepeatedTiming[r4 = f4[a, b];];
t5 = First@RepeatedTiming[r5 = f5[a, b];];
t6 = First@RepeatedTiming[r6 = f6[a, b];];
r1 == r2 == r3 == r4 == r5 == r6
```

> True

```
timings = {t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6};
Grid[Prepend[SortBy[Last]@Transpose[{funcs, timings}], {"function", "timing"}], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

> $\begin{array}{|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{function} & \text{timing} \\
> \hline
>  \text{f4} & 0.0009 \\
> \hline
>  \text{f6} & 0.0028 \\
> \hline
>  \text{f1} & 0.003 \\
> \hline
>  \text{f2} & 0.0034 \\
> \hline
>  \text{f5} & 0.004 \\
> \hline
>  \text{f3} & 0.012 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

With `na = 1000` we get

> $\begin{array}{|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{function} & \text{timing} \\
> \hline
>  \text{f4} & 0.0014 \\
> \hline
>  \text{f3} & 0.016 \\
> \hline
>  \text{f2} & 0.0737 \\
> \hline
>  \text{f6} & 0.117 \\
> \hline
>  \text{f5} & 0.118 \\
> \hline
>  \text{f1} & 0.59 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

Comment: `Cases[B, Alternatives@@A]` is real-world poetry.

Comment: +1. Also: `SortBy[A, PositionIndex[B]]`

Comment: I think the ony valid solutions are the `SortBy` ones; the others do not work when there are repeated elements in A

Comment: @Fortsaint, I think with duplicate elements in `A` (and in `B`), `SortBy` methods do not work (other methods do work).

Comment: @kglr Consider this: `A = {5, 2, 8, 5, 8}, B = {9, 2, 6, 8, 5, 1}`. The `SortBy` methods gives `{2, 8, 8, 5, 5}`while the `Cases`/`Select` methods gives `{2, 8, 5}`. Which is right? I still think the `SortBy` are. He needs ".. to arrange the elements in A as given in B.". Deleting duplicates is not rearranging

Comment: @Fortsaint, I read (I may be wrong)  "All of the elements of A are members of B" as  `B` is `A` with additional elements  shuffled. So, for your example modified to make `B` have the same duplications, say,  `A = {5, 2, 8, 5, 8}; B = {9, 2, 6, 8,5,8, 5, 1} ;`  we get `{2, 8, 8, 5, 5}` from `SortBy[PositionIndex@B]@A` and `{2, 8, 5, 8, 5}` from `Cases/Select/DeleteCases`.

Comment: @WReach good idea to use an `Association` in `SortBy`. It's not in the documentation and looks very useful for future reference.

Comment: Beautiful one-liners! I did not specify in my question but in my case, `B` only has unique elements. I have gone with the following solution: `OrderLike[A_List,B_List]:=SortBy[A,FirstPosition[B,#]&];` I took out some of the syntactic sugar for us mere mortals.

Comment: @c186282 nice final implementation! Great way to cross simplicity with explanation. I love one-liners. I'm commenting to compliment this thread, and also to ask that you post this final code in your question, possibly crediting those that helped? So it doesn't get lost in the comments :D

Comment: @Roman & WReach & kglr, could you provide some wiki input on this technique? I recognize the power of this combination, but I would like more explanation on how you all view it. Does it provide for a speed-up, or a more applicable nature (generality in implementation)?

Comment: @c186282 it looks like you've chosen the slowest of all proposed methods. The one you picked has a runtime that scales quadratically with the lengths of the lists, whereas other methods scale linearly.

Comment: @Roman Bummer! I'll have to look more closely at the others. Luckily, for my application, the lengths of my lists will not get very large $<100$

Comment: @CATrevillian, updated with some timing comparisons.

Comment: ... and just noticed that Roman already posted a more detailed comparison half hour earlier:)

Answer (score 6):

## benchmarks

No new methods here, only benchmarks of methods given in @kglr's answer.

```
Clear[timings];
timings[n_Integer] := timings[n] = 
  Module[{A, B, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6},
    B = RandomSample[Range[n]];
    A = RandomSample[B, Floor[n/2]];
    t1 = First[AbsoluteTiming[a1 = SortBy[Position[B, #] &]@A;]];
    t2 = First[AbsoluteTiming[a2 = SortBy[A, FirstPosition[B, #] &];]];
    t3 = First[AbsoluteTiming[a3 = SortBy[PositionIndex@B]@A;]];
    t4 = First[AbsoluteTiming[a4 = Cases[Alternatives @@ A]@B;]];
    t5 = First[AbsoluteTiming[a5 = Select[MatchQ[Alternatives @@ A]]@B;]];
    t6 = First[AbsoluteTiming[a6 = DeleteCases[Except[Alternatives @@ A]]@B;]];
    If[a1 == a2 == a3 == a4 == a5 == a6, {t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6}, $Failed]]

ListLogLogPlot[Transpose[Table[Thread[{n, timings[n]}],
  {n, Round[10^Range[3, 9/2, 1/4]]}]],
  Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> Range[6],
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"n", "time [s]"}]
```

[image]

Observations:

- Methods 5 and 6 are almost indistinguishable in their timings.
- Methods 3 & 4 scale linearly with $n$.
- Methods 1, 2, 5, 6 scale quadratically with $n$.
- Method 4 is the absolute front-runner: `Cases[Alternatives @@ A]@B`. Fast & poetic.

Comment: Very nice I have changed my choise of method. I cannot miss out on fast and poetic.

Comment: Always good to see [visuals](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197275/4626) of benchmarks.